# How can I delete this non-existant directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, rm, fedora-17

A few weeks ago I mapped/browsed (can't remember) to a network share on my local network. It worked fine at that point. I haven't used the machine since then, until today. As you can see below, something is not correct.

How can I delete the directory/file indicated in the image? I cannot `chown` or `chmod` even as `root` nor can I remove it.

My Operating System is Fedora 17.

[image: Delete meeeeeeeeeee]

Comment: Does this issue survive a reboot? Looks like a stale mount. How is this directory mounted if it is a remote one?

Answer (score 1):

If you have mounted a network share or another filesystem, **`umount`** will unmount it, close the connection, etc.

In case `umount` hangs (network problems or whatever), you can use `umount -l` for "lazy detach", which will detach the mountpoint immediately, and perform any disconnections in background.

Answer (score 0):

To take one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541533/only-questionmarks-in-linux-dirlisting):

> If you do a chmod 0600 or 0400 on any directory, you can easily reproduce this behavior. Add execute permission to the dir, and it'll work fine.

It seems to be the most common answer to this behavior. I can't seem to reproduce it on my end.

Q: did you mount a share to this directory at some point?

Comment: A missing +x permission has similar symptoms, but it would affect _all_ files & subdirs inside a particular directory – but not the directory itself, since stat() [to determine file] only requires access to the _parent_.